# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getPart(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/servlet/http/Part;

Tags: java, maven, servlets

This Problem asked many times on stack-overflow and i checked all and tried all possibility what others said to remove above error but still not figure out. 
Servlet api-3.1, Using Maven build tool, JRE 1.7 Used, my web-inf folder contain same javax.servlet 3.1 as i define in pom.xml file.

Here is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ebooks</groupId>
  <artifactId>project</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>InsaneNerds Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



     <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>







       <dependency>  
       <groupId>javax</groupId>  
       <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>  
       <version>6.0</version>  
       <scope>provided</scope>  
     </dependency> 


       <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>  
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>  
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>  
    <version>4.1.9.Final</version>  
</dependency>  

<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.restfb</groupId>
    <artifactId>restfb</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.0</version>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>project</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

What i want i want to upload a file and store it in my sql database primarlity  i used this tutorial http://www.codejava.net/coding/upload-files-to-database-servlet-jsp-mysql to do this but i am getting above error.

What i tried:- 
1. I checked my dependency
2. My Web-INF folder
3. All possible solution i.e provided on internet but still not figure out.

Is there any other method to upload file from html and store it in mysql database.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

You have the servlet-api marked as `provided` -- as you should -- but this means you are dependent on the version provided by your application server. (`provided` says "don't bundle this library in the WAR; the app server will **provide** it.") You haven't said what app server or version you are using but if it's, for example, Tomcat 5.5, then I'm not surprised at all by this error, since this method was added in 3.0 of the servlet spec.

Comment: Hmmm, curious. Tomcat 7 supports servlet 3.0... How about the first few lines of your web.xml file―are you declaring using version 3.0 of the schema?

Answer (score 0):

It happend to me when I used a servlet 3.0 spec but the pom has 3.1